# Can we apply Quad-Tree to a non-square rectangle?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, quadtree

I am trying to implement a 2-D fast collision detection with Quad-Tree.

AFAIK, Quad-Tree divides a region into 4 sub-regions, north-west, north-east, south-east and south-west. This dividing works perfectly with a **square**. But what if the region is a **non-square rectangle**? In that case, we cannot divide the long edge and the short edge evenly, and the short edge determins how far we can divide.

Am I right on this? Is that meant to be?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a square quadtree whose sides are as long as the longest side of your rectangle?  There won't ever be anything in the empty space, but that should be a negligible overhead.

Comment: You mean add some padding. That's a good idea. But what about a region in arbitrary shape. Shall I enclose it in a square as small as possible?

Comment: That's the idea!  The quadtree will still work the same if it encloses any arbitrary space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take the max of width, height of the bounding box of the region of interest as the side length of the quad tree.

Another solution:
Two quad tree implementtaions that i have seen uses a rectangle internaly, so that would run out of the box, even if the provided root bounds is not a square. They divide both the width and the height of the bounds in each subdivision step.
 But note that there are ovr 10 different Quadtree types. I am talking about Rectangle Quadtrees.

One implemention explictly uses a a side length which is divided by 2, so that would not work fine for non square root bounds.

However, I still recommend my first sentence, better use a square as root bounds.
This then works for all quad tree types.